# Extract First Name of the sender

Tags: vba, outlook

After receiving an email I want to extract the sender's First Name into the email body, to avoid name typos.

I managed with Name and Surname, but I can’t extract and display First Name only.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Dodanie_imienia()
On Error GoTo brak_aktywnego
Dim objItem As MailItem: Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
On Error GoTo 0
Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector: Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
Dim objDoc As Object: Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor 'Word.Document
Dim objWord As Object: Set objWord = objDoc.Application 'Word.Application
Dim objSel As Object: Set objSel = objWord.Selection 'Word.Selection
Dim objItem2 As Object: Set objItem2 = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Dim tekst$: tekst = "Hi " & objItem2.SenderName & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

 objSel.TypeText tekst

Exit Sub
brak_aktywnego:
 If Err.Number = 91 Then _
 MsgBox "Utwórz wiadomość do edycji.", vbExclamation, "LB" Else _
 MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "LB"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you assume there is a first name and last name? All you get is a display name - it can be just the email address, or anything the sender wanted to show. You are of course free to parse the display name assuming it will be in the format "first last" or "last, first". Or "first middle last". Or any other format.

In case of an Exchange sender, you can, of course, retrieve the `AddressEntry` object from `MailItem.Sender` and check if `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser` is not null. If you have a valid object, you can use `ExchangeUser.FirstName` and `ExchangeUser.LastName`.

Comment: Thank you, below line of code got me first name for exchange user:
Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Sender.getexchangeuser.firstname

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Done...sorry not very frequent visitor on this path and missed. :P

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line:

```
Dim tekst$: tekst = "Hi " & Split(objItem2.SenderName)(0) & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```