# Is there a way to reply with sender's name in Outlook?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Is there a way that when I click "*Reply*" or "*Reply All*" on a message, to input "Hello Sender's First Name,"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook reply with individual recipient names (sender name of original email)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105073/outlook-reply-with-individual-recipient-names-sender-name-of-original-email)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048701/extract-first-name-of-the-sender

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro or add-in where you could handle the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(even)) and [ReplyAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyall(even)) events.

The `Reply` event is fired when the user selects the `Reply` action for an item, or when the `Reply` method is called for the item. The new item being sent in response to the original message is passed as a parameter, so you can set it up according to your needs. For example:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As MailItem 
 
Sub Initialize_Handler() 
 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
 Set Response.Body = "Hello dear!" 
End Sub
```

The `ReplyAll` event is fired when the user selects the `ReplyAll` action for an item, or when the `ReplyAll` method is called for the item.